# Eclipse C/C++ Debug Variable Default Format as Hex

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, format, hex

Is there a way to set default format for debugging variables to HEX?
I am using:
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
Build id: 20191212-1212

I've seen [this](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/10/01/debugging-variables-in-hexadecimal-with-eclipse/) old post but on my eclipse version there is no option for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the option to custom the number format was removed from eclipse preferences and should  be returned sometime.

From eclipse Bugzilla: [bug 373550](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373550) (status: open with dependency)

> "Note that with the removal of CDI (Bug 484900), this preference page was removed."

Answer (score 0):

On Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16.0):

In view Variables

- go to view menu (3 vertical dots)
- Number Format: Hex